# How can I select for the latest row based on two different attributes?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to select the latest activity code (A, V, W, J) for the following transactions (109, 154, 982, 745)   for my employees.  I need to know what my employee last transaction was (from the list) that had one of those activity codes.  There are 2 tables involved with a join on the employee ID.
Table 1:

```
|Emp_id  |  STUFF
|  1     |  stuff
|  2     |  stuff
|  3     |  stuff
```

Table 2:

```
|Emp_id   |  date      | act_code   |  trans 
|   1     |  1/1/17    |   A        |    109
|   1     |  3/4/12    |   X        |    203
|   1     |  2/14/09   |   A        |    154
|   2     |  1/1/17    |   A        |    110
|   2     |  6/6/13    |   V        |    109
|   3     |  12/13/16  |   J        |    982
|   3     |  11/23/14  |   W        |    745
|   4     |  12/13/16  |   X        |    154
|   4     |  11/23/14  |   W        |    745
```

What I’d like to return is:

```
|Emp_id  |  STUFF  |  date      | act_code   |  trans 
|  1     |  stuff  |  1/1/17    |   A        |    109
|  3     |  stuff  |  12/13/16  |   J        |    982
```

Emp 2 would not be selected because the latest trans is not one of the correct values.  Emp 4 would not be selected because the latest act_code is not one of the correct values.  Anyone have an idea as to how to go about this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: emp 2 has the latest value `a`..why shouldn't it be selected?

Comment: because the transaction is 110 (not in the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to partition the rows by `emp_id` and order the rows by `date`:

```
SELECT t2.emp_id, t1.stuff, t2.date, t2.act_code, t2.trans,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY t2.emp_id ORDER BY t2.date DESC) RN
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id;
```

Then filter this to only the most recent records (`RN = 1`) that have values in your lists with an outer select:

```
SELECT emp_id, stuff, date, act_code, trans
FROM (
    SELECT t2.emp_id, t1.stuff, t2.date, t2.act_code, t2.trans,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY t2.emp_id ORDER BY t2.date DESC) RN
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
     ) A
WHERE RN = 1
AND trans IN (109, 154, 982, 745)
AND act_code IN ('A', 'V', 'W', 'J');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  This seems to be giving me the results I asked for!  I had a quick question though.  This is returning the latest act code and trans.  Is there a way to return the same data, but after 10/01/2016? (i should have added this to the initial question; it was an oversight on my part.)

Comment: @user7002207 No worries, happy to help.  When you say after 10/01/2016, do you mean you don't want to see the record unless the latest record is after 10/01/2016?  If so, you can just add `AND date > '20161001'` to the outer select filters.  Not sure I'm understanding that right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `first_value` to get the latest values of act_code,trans and then check if they are in the specified list.

```
select * from (
select distinct t1.emp_id,t1.stuff,
max(t2.date) over(partition by t2.emp_id) as latest_date,
first_value(t2.act_code) over(partition by t2.emp_id order by t2.date desc) as latest_act_code,
first_value(t2.trans) over(partition by t2.emp_id order by t2.date desc) as latest_trans
from tbl1 t1
join tbl2 t2 on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id
) t 
where latest_act_code in ('A','V','W','J') and latest_trans in (109, 154, 982, 745)
```